# How to Open SSLSocket directly to my glassfish default self signed certificate, in android?

Tags: android, ssl, glassfish

as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#WarningsSslSocket

in this peace of code of the site

```
SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("gmail.com", 443);
HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
SSLSession s = socket.getSession();

if (!hv.verify("mail.google.com", s)) {
    throw new SSLHandshakeException("Expected mail.google.com, "
                                "found " + s.getPeerPrincipal());
}
```

my code always pass false in the verfy and then the getPeerPrincipal() trows an error null

```
public class Teste extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {


        SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket("192.168.13.103", 8181);

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();

        SSLSession sslSession = sslSocket.getSession();

        if (!hostnameVerifier.verify("192.168.13.103", sslSession)) {

            System.out.println(sslSession.getPeerHost());

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);

    }

    return null;

}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand your code, you are trying to connect to the HTTP socket of your Glassfish server (port 8181), so no SSL/TSL will respond. Then false was the good answer.

Comment: What should i put here createSocket("192.168.13.103", 8181) ?

Comment: Just verify that this port was used by the https listener or support https, look at the admin console. If it's good, this is your saviour http://www.smartjava.org/content/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors